# Ember Model mismatch

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to facilitate defining rates by multiple dimensions. in the backend a table is used which has two important columns key and value. value contains json data. this makes it convenient to define rates in multiple ways. one such possibility is shown below

```
key - user:1
value - 
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "activity": 1,
    "effectiveDate": null,
    "rate": {
      "currency": "currency:1",
      "amount": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "activity": 2,
    "effectiveDate": null,
    "rate": {
      "currency": "currency:1",
      "amount": 20
    }
  }
]
```

on the UI this needs to be shown across multiple rows. uniqueness is defined by user, activity and effectiveDate. 
so it will be -

```
user,  activity,  effectivedate, currency,   amount
user:1 activity:1                currency:1, 10
user:1 activity:2                currency:1, 20
```

so the model will be as below:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  userId: DS.attr('string'),
  activityId: DS.attr('string'),
  rateAmount: DS.attr('number'),
  effectiveDate: DS.attr('date'),
  rateCurrencyId: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

how can i transform the single key value from API to the model shown above? a delete of the record in the front end doesn't necessary mean a key value delete.

should i create two models one corresponding to the UI and another for key value and transform updates from one model to another and then save the second model to push it back to server? that seems cumbersome.

i checked transform but that helps if i have to tweak the data type. here number of records of the models don't match.

what is the right way to deal with such scenarios in ember?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create model specific serializer and override [normalizeResponse](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_normalizing-adapter-responses) and convert payload it into the required format of the model you want,

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  userId: DS.attr('string'),
  activityId: DS.attr('string'),
  rateAmount: DS.attr('number'),
  effectiveDate: DS.attr('date'),
  rateCurrencyId: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. serialzer is great if there is a one to one mapping between the two. here the API response will result into multiple records of the ember model. would serializer be still applicable?

Comment: Yes still applicable In your case you can define only one model to represent all the attributes server sent.

Comment: let's say user deletes a record. ember will then issue a DELETE with id of the record that was deleted. 
here the actual request shouldn't be a delete but should be a POST. how can we convert a delete request to a POST inside serializer? aren't we violating purpose of serializer when we attempt that?

Comment: @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy if I understand you correctly then you can do that nothing wrong in it. refer [#3099](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3099) ds-improved-ajax feature but unfortunately they [disabled this feature](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4686) in favour of [RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/171)